# Как решить проблему с libSOIL.a: error LNK2019:?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Дело в том, что я невнимательно смотрел, как все делается, и не переименовал `libSOIL.a` в `SOIL.lib`. Спустя некоторое время заметил ошибку, переименовал, но теперь компилятор выдает ошибку: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Engine\Graphics\SOIL\lib\libSOIL.a'`
Как мне сделать так, чтобы он даже не смотрел в сторону `libSOIL.a`? Удаление не помогает.

Вопрос все еще актуальный. "Правой кнопкой мыши в проекте по папке SOIL -> Include in project" - не прокатывает

Answer (score 0):

Итак, дело не в моей невнимательности. Помогло вот это: [скачал с гитхаба файлы, совместимые с Visual Studio 2017](https://github.com/Friduric/simple-opengl-image-library/blob/master/README.md)